# Problems with session in requests on python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Im trying to login to Plus500 with in python. Everething is ok, with status code 200, and response from server. But the server will not accept my requuest.

I did every single step that the webBrowser thoes. Headers like web browser. Always the same result.

```
url = "https://trade.plus500.com/AppInitiatedImm/WebTrader2/?webvisitid=" + self.tokesession+ "&page=login&isInTradeContext=false"

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
              "Host": "trade.plus500.com",
              "Connection": "keep-alive",
              "Referer": "https://app.plus500.com/trade",
              "Cookie":"webvisitid=" + self.cookiesession + ";"+\
                       "IP="+self.hasip}
param = "ClientType=WebTrader2&machineID=33b5db48501c9b0e5552ea135722b2c6&PrimaryMachineId=33b5db48501c9b0e5552ea135722b2c6&hl=en&cl=en-GB&AppVersion=87858&refurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.plus500.co.uk%2F&SessionID=0&SubSessionID=0"
response = self.session.request(method="POST",
                                url=url,
                                params=param,
                                headers=header,stream=True)
```

The code above is the initialization of the web app. after that do the login. But it always come up with JSON reply : AppSessionRquired. I think I already try everinthing that i can think of. If some one as idea.

Comment: Could you post your full code so we can help you? You may want to read this to improve your question and help us help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Solved! thank you anyway.

Comment: Could you post your solution in case someone has the same issue in the future? Thanks.

Comment: The problem wanst in the code. Was just diferent session names.